# convert math equation to python

Tags: python

[image: I need to convert this formula to python]

```
def polar_distance(r1, fi1, r2, fi2):
    return math.sqrt (r1 ** 2 + r2 ** 2 - 2 * r1 * r2 * math.cos(fi1-fi2))

polar_distance(1,30,4,90)
```

I am getting wrong result what did I miss?
Result shoud be 3.6 but mine returns 4.9

Comment: Judging by the values 30 and 90, `fi1` and `fi2` seem to be degrees, but `math.cos` (and similar functions in most math libraries) expect radians. You can convert them with `math.radians(fi1)`.

Comment: fi1 and fi2 are in degrees

Answer (score 0):

Convert your angles to radians

```
import math
def polar_distance(r1, fi1, r2, fi2):
    return math.sqrt (r1 ** 2 + r2 ** 2 - 2 * r1 * r2 * math.cos(math.radians(fi1-fi2)))

polar_distance(1,30,4,90)
```

Out:

```
3.605551275463989
```